# I am getting an error of no table found when preparing a statement when using sqlite3 a in web application

Tags: php, sqlite, geany, ampps

I am trying to use Sqlite3 to develop a web application. However, every time I keep on getting a cannot find table error when I am using the prepared statement. Please assist as best as you can with any further troubleshooting steps or courses of action that may be useful.

Here is the specific error:
SQLite3::prepare(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, no such table: test in C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\onhand\classes.php on line 23

Environment:

Ampps

Geany for coding

php7.4(including making the sqlite connections)

Apache

Sqlite3 (downloaded off sqlite website and used to create the database)

Sqlite Studio (used to create the tables)

Code:

```
$db=new SQLite3("C:\Program Files\Ampps\www\onhand\inventory.db");
$stmt=$db->prepare('select * from test);
$result=$stmt->execute();
var_dump($result->fetchArray());
```

Troubleshooting steps tried:

Renamed the table- Same result of no connection

Deleted the table and recreated it- Same result of no connection

Made a copy of the database and placed in php folder- Same result of no connection

Declared absolute path of database instead of relative path-Same result of no connection

Tried to use PDO instead of native sqlite3 for php- Same result of no connection

Verified that all letters are lower case and that the spelling matches

I tried as the whoever associated with the path post to use the slashes as a / and a double slash as well. Those failed as well.